# How do I get ybsql results to load without requiring hitting the enter button repeatedly?

Tags: load, enter, yellowbrick

We're using ybsql now via command prompt.  If a ybsl query has more than x results, it's requiring me to hit enter while being prompted with '-- More --'.  I just want it to load all results of the query. right now, it's only loading 65 rows of results. help

Answer (score 0):

found a ybsql user guide that was really helpful and found the answer:
\pset pager 0

Comment: Hey there king53214, you should cite the guide you found in your answer, and perhaps paraphrase it/quote it with your solution.